# Using Javascript to set maxlength of a form text field, not working

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this in my javascript file:

```
function yeahbaby() {
document.getElementByName("surname").maxLength = "40";
}
```

which is loaded in this line of code in my htm file

```
<form action="blah blah blah" 
method="post" name="medicalform" onsubmit="return unrelated validation function();" 
onload="yeahbaby();">
```

With the final result being that this input field

```
Surname: <input type="text" name="surname">
```

is limited to a maximum of 40 characters.

However, it doesn't actually put the limit on the input field, as I can type many more than 40 characters (or whatever I try changing it to).

I know I can change it in the htm file directly but I need to actually change it using javascript. I've literally been trying to fix this for the past two hours. Have I missed something?

Edit: I've tried getElementsbyName (adding the S) and it's still not working.

Edit 2: document.getElementsByName("surname")[0].setAttribute('maxLength', '40'); doesn't work either

Edit 3: https://pastebin.com/7SNmmcSN a link to both my HTML and javascript files.

Comment: The `<input>` element does not have an `.id` set. Why do you not use `maxlength` attribute at `html`?

Comment: I'm not using an ID to refer to it, I'm using the name. Do I have to use an ID?

Comment: Did not notice that. Why do you not set value of `maxLength` at `html`?

Comment: @guest271314 It's actually for an assignment for my uni course, they're telling me to apply all of the constraints in a separate javascript file rather than editing the HTML file

Comment: Add `"s"` following `Element`

Comment: I'm trying document.getElementsByName("surname").maxLength = "40"; and it's still not capping it

Comment: You still need `[0]` following `("surname")`

Answer (score 1):

Try [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp):

```
document.getElementsByName("surname")[0].setAttribute('maxLength', '40');
```

Comment: Missing `"s"` following `Element`

Comment: Still not working. Will it stop when I try typing the 41st character or does it only notify when I try to submit it?

Comment: Does the top part go in my javascript file? I need to have a seperate file, what is that yeahbaby(); outside of the function doing?

Comment: Sorry, I copypasta'd the OPs code and updated for `setAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you put the JavaScript as a funciton but not invoking the function.

Also note that it is `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName` and it will return an HTML collection not a single element.

So, you have to specify the index `[0`].

Check the below snippet.

```js
function yeahbaby() {
document.getElementsByName("surname")[0].setAttribute("maxLength", "40");
}
yeahbaby();
```

```html
<form action="blah blah blah" 
method="post" name="medicalform" onsubmit="return unrelated validation function();" 
onload="yeahbaby();">


Surname: <input type="text" name="surname">
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what's going wrong. Maybe the yeahbaby(); function isn't being loaded? I did have problems earlier with trying to get .onload to work.

Comment: add the JavaScript code just above the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: The Javascript has to be in a seperate .js file - that's what my assignment is telling me to do. I can't put the javascript in the HTML document, I can only do `<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidation.js"></script>`

Comment: add it just above the `</body>` tag. as `<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidation.js"></script></body>`

Comment: That didn't change anything =/

Comment: Try clearing cache and reload. If it is not solved, update the question with some HTML.

Comment: don't add `yeahbaby();` as form#onload. instead. add this `<script type="text/javascript" src="formValidation.js">yeahbaby();</script></body>` @anon

Comment: It's still not working :'( hahaha. Thankyou so much for your patience though. I'm honestly confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: The weirdest thing is, the other functions in formValidation.js work perfectly, it's just the yeahbaby() that isn't.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Thankyou so much for your time though :) I'll just have to come back to this later.